# I don't understand what a character says in a TV programme

Tags: vocabulary, north-american-english

I'm a non-native English speaker and English is my second language. I've been watching an episode of one of my favourite children's TV programmes for a minute and I already don't understand what one of the characters' voice actor says. Could somebody click the link and tell me what the character says.
I guess it's probably because the character mumbles and pushing the words together at the same, but still I want to know what he says.
Thank you so much in advance!

The TV programme is called Monster By Mistake.
The link is here: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ch1-m2gXuSM**
*The time is 01:39*
The phrase starts: ''Oh, boy...

Comment: Oh boy, here we go...

Comment: @Conrado That's what I heard as well, but I wasn't sure.  It's hardly audible. Thank you so much for the confirmation!!!

Comment: Right next to 'like' and 'dislike' buttons, there's an icon looks like °°°, click that icon and then select **open transcript**, it will show the transcript of the whole video.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Trust me, I know about that function, but it's not always right, just like it isn't in this case. It's probably bc it's an auto generated subtitles.